# Oracle bulk insert by querydsl

Tags: oracle, querydsl

I want to do bulk_insert on Oracle by querydsl.

I use **insert.setBatchToBulk(true)** and querydsl as a results generates following query

```
INSERT ALL
INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
select * from dual
```

This query execution(**executeWithKeys**()) in oracle brings unique constraint error , reason of unique pk.

Any solutuons?

Comment: "Any solutions?"  is a broad question in this scenario.  There was a reason why unique key/ primary was used on the table in the first place. The query you have generated  is trying to insert duplicate records. Since single statements are atomic ( i.e they either succeed or fail completely ), your whole query including all insert fails. You have to tell us how exactly you want the data to be inserted and saved in the tables after the operation.Only then it could  lead to a feasible solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. The query is  generated by queryDsl,(using batch insert). "mytable" 's identity is autoIncremented and generated query does not contain identity column .  

Generally: I want to do bulk_insert in "mytbale"(which identity is autoIncrement) on oracle using queryDsl.